# How can i find the "non-unique" rows?

Tags: pandas, csv, datetime

I imported CSV files with over 500k rows, one year, every minute.
To merge two of this files, i want so re-sample the index to every minute:

```
Temp= pd.read_csv("Temp.csv", sep=";", decimal="," , thousands='.'  ,encoding="cp1252")

Temp["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(Temp["Time"],dayfirst=True)
Temp.set_index(['Time'], inplace=True)
Temp= Temp.resample('1Min').ffill()
```

But I got the error:

> cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit

How can i find the "non-unique" rows?

Comment: Probably it's crazy to re-index 500k rows every minute. The time is just not enough to finish before the next update shall start. Execute the import only once and see if the message is still coming.

Comment: 500k are the collected data from one year. Every minute one value, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
Temp= pd.read_csv("Temp.csv", sep=";", decimal="," , thousands='.'  ,encoding="cp1252")
Temp.drop_duplicates(inplace=True) 
Temp["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(Temp["Time"],dayfirst=True)
Temp.set_index(['Time'], inplace=True)
Temp= Temp.resample('1Min').ffill()
```

I used:

```
len(Temp.index)
```

and

```
len(set(Temp.index))
```

to find out, that there are Dublicates

Answer (score 1):

You can return a slice of all duplicated rows using `df.duplicated()`

In your case

```
Temp[Temp.duplicated(subset=None, keep=False)]
```

where subset can be changed if you want to find duplicates only in a specific column, and keep = False specifies to display all rows that are duplicated, regardless if its the first or second appearance.

Documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html